# Saving appropriate id from multiple models into one model, which is associated with each of those multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Recommendation, SecondRecommendation, ThirdRecommendation models. Each has many corrections. The Correction model has recommendation_id, second_recommendation_id, and so on (not null true). How can I create this Correction and save the appropriate recommendation id as well?

My current attempt in corrections controller, create action:

```rb
        recommendation_id = params[:recommendation_id]
        correction = Correction.new(correction_params)
        correction.user_id = current_user.id 
        recommendation = Recommendation.find(recommendation_id)

        case recommendation.class.name
            when "Recommendation"
                correction.recommendation_id = recommendation_id
            when "SecondRecommendation"
                correction.second_recommendation_id = recommendation_id
            when "ThirdRecommendation"
                correction.third_recommendation_id = recommendation_id
            else 
        end

        if correction.save
```

This doesn't work -- can't find Recommendation id, and also it's not touching on Second and Third. Is what I'm trying even possible? I'd really appreciate help.

I see this:   `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "correction"=>{"one"=>"hello there"}, "commit"=>"Post", "recommendation_id"=>"62"}`
If I add this to SecondRecommendation, then it shows second_recomendation_id. And so on.

UPDATE: I've tried this in the console and ran errors.messages. I got:

```
 => {:second_recommendation=>["must exist"], :third_recommendation=>["must exist"], :fourth_recommendation=>["must exist"], :fifth_recommendation=>["must exist"]}
```

which is weird, because my schema shows:

```rb
    t.bigint "second_recommendation_id"
    t.bigint "third_recommendation_id"
    t.bigint "fourth_recommendation_id"
    t.bigint "fifth_recommendation_id"
```

Comment: please add the contents of the received params hash

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand exactly the problems you're seeing. But just b/c the schema has the `second_recommendation_id` etc doesn't mean that the model will be valid. The errors.messages indicates that validation is failing. What are the validations on the Correction model related to recommendation_ids?

Comment: @LesNightingill I've tried again, and as long as I input user_id and recomendation_id, the correction model gets created. I think the issue here then is how to get the relevant recommendation id (of the five) and save that into the respective column in the corrections table.

Comment: put a `debugger` statement before the `case recommendation.class.name` statement and inspect. What is the value of `recommendation.class.name`?